# "Once is enough" or "One time is enough" or something else?

Tags: phrase-request, phrase-choice

Which of the selected phrases sounds natural?

> No need to do this several times. **One time is enough.**
>
> No need to do this several times. **Single time is enough.**
>
> No need to do this several times. **Once is enough.**

Or maybe you would say some completely different phrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, only the last sounds at all natural. The punctuation is 'unusual' though - I would probably use a comma rather than a full-stop.